# How to change the font in LineLegend?

Tags: plotting, legending, style

Is it possible to change the font in `LineLegend`? In fact, I need a mathematical font (like Times) in this part.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the option [`LabelStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/[<code>LabelStyle</code>(https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LabelStyle.html).html) with suboptions [`FontFamily`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FontFamily.html), [`FontSize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FontSize.html), [`FontColor`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FontColor.html) etc to set font properties:

```
LineLegend[{Red, Green, Blue}, {"red", "green", "blue"}, 
 LegendLabel -> Style["legend", FontFamily -> "Arial", 32, Black], 
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", FontSize -> 24, 
   FontColor -> Purple, FontSlant -> Italic, FontWeight -> "Heavy"}]
```

[image]

For the options `FontSize`, `FontColor`, `FontSlant`, `FontWeight`, Wolfram language is able to infer the associated option if you provide only the values of these options:

```
LineLegend[{Red, Green, Blue}, {"red", "green", "blue"}, 
 LegendLabel -> Style["legend", FontFamily -> "Arial", 32, Black], 
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 24, Purple, Italic, Bold}]
```

> same picture